# Angular 2 - ngFor display last 3 items in array

Tags: angular, ngfor

got an array with many projects and i want to display the last 3 projects.

got in my html

```
          <li *ngFor="let project of projects;">
            <h2>{{ project.name }}</h2>
            <p>{{ project.meta_desciption }}</p>
          </li>
```

it s displaying all the project now (over 20).
how can i display only the last 3?
I think i need to use "last" somewere in my code, but can't figure it out
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let project of (projects | slice:projects.length - 4);">
```

You might need some additional `null` check for `projects` or ensure that it is always an array.

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis and also don't need projects.length. You can just use: `<li *ngFor="let project of projects | slice:-4">`

Answer (score 4):

Gunter's answer above didn't work in my case. I was able to accomplish the same thing but slightly different:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index">
    <li *ngIf="i > projects.length - 4">
        <h2>{{ project.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ project.meta_desciption }}</p>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

If the index of the loop is greater then the length of the array minus 4. So if the length is less then 3 it prints all, if it is 3 or greater it just prints the last 3 in whatever order they come in.

Comment: Actually. This answer would make a big problem if the <ng-container> has any style by it's own. 
the page would still render the ng-container with it's style.
That's why angular slice pipe comes in handy

Answer (score 3):

As answered by Gunter above, you might also need to check the length of "projects" is greater than 4.

```
<div *ngIf="projects.length>4">
    <li *ngFor="let project of projects;">
        <h2>{{ project.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ project.meta_desciption }}</p>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case for getting last three project below code work perfect no need to check projects length it work for any length of array.

```js
<li *ngFor="let project of (projects | slice: -3)">
```

---