# How to only show last 5 message using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor, angular9

I have a situation, my `*ngFor` loops like this on some incoming messages.

```
<ul id="messages">
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages;let i = index">
      <span id="actualMessage" [innerHTML]="isSystemMessage(message,i)"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I handle it in my `isSystemMessage` like this

```
    public isSystemMessage(message: string,i:number) {
        return  "<strong>" + i+':  '+message + "</strong>" 
    }
```

Now, it displays the messages fine, but **what if I only want to see the last 5 messages and delete all the entries above it?**

What I thought of adding some code like this.

```
public isSystemMessage(message: string,i:number) {
        if (i+1==5) {
            // TODO: Delete the all the other entries from the webpage and only show last 5 at a time?
        }
        return  "<strong>" + i+':  '+message + "</strong>" // otherwise, return the message
    }
```

Is there's any way to delete entries and delete them from the UI as well?.

Comment: Sort your messages in reverse order then take first 5 and show or if only last 5 needs to be shown then take only last 5 and then use ngfor on it

Comment: You receive the messages in a main holder object. And copy the latest 5 to the collection that you bind to the ngFor

Comment: @muasif80, if it's possible, can you please write a small code snippet in the answer, I guess I understand some parts of what you're trying to say but to completely.

Comment: Also, say I have sixth message incoming, how can I delete the first message div from the UI as well?.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38976012/578855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `slice`

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages | slice: (messages.length > 5 ? messages.length - 5 : 0); index as i">{{message}}</div>
```

Here is a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-ngfor-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

With this methode, you will only display last five messsages

```
<ul id="messages">
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages;let i = index">
      <span *ngIf="(messages.length>5 && messages.length-i <= 5) || messages.length<=5" id="actualMessage" [innerHTML]="isSystemMessage(message,i)"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is that helpful ?